# Have a text input in a draggable rectangle on a HTML canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

For a project I'm working on, I have a canvas on which I draw several rectangles. These rectangles can be moved or resized with the mouse and some mouse events. But I'm currently stuck. I want to have a text input on each of the rectangles drawn, and that text input must move with the rectangle it is on.

My rectangles are drawn with this constructor :

```
// Constructor for Shape objects to hold data for all drawn objects.
// For now they will just be defined as rectangles.
function Shape(id, questionId, label, isCorrect, weight, x, y, w, h, fill) {
  // This is a very simple and unsafe constructor. All we're doing is checking if the values exist.
  // "x || 0" just means "if there is a value for x, use that. Otherwise use 0."
  // But we aren't checking anything else! We could put "Lalala" for the value of x 
  this.x = x || 0;
  this.y = y || 0;
  this.w = w || 1;
  this.h = h || 1;
  this.fill = fill || '#AAAAAA';

  this.id = id;
  this.questionId = questionId;
  this.weight = weight || 0;
  this.text = label || "zspot";
  this.hasChanged = false;
  this.checked = isCorrect || false;
  this.isNew = false;
}

// Draws this shape to a given context
Shape.prototype.draw = function (ctx) {
  ctx.fillStyle = this.fill;
  ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
}
```

Here is a JSFiddle with the my code : https://jsfiddle.net/sd48fbph/13/. (May be a little long and messy, sorry)